# I am unable to install eclipse IDE.The error is"*failed load the JNI shared library*".How can i install that?

Tags: java, android

when I searched online about some suggested to regedit the java version but its not showing the "java" when I open regedit...

Comment: Don't fiddle with regedit.  Install a proper version of Java.

Comment: I downloaded the new java jdk...but the thing is its an application... when I click on it it gets installed and I can't open any bin folder to take the path....even after its installation the new eclipse pops with same error...

Comment: Then you probably did not download a proper version of Java.

Comment: I have downloaded the 64 bit version of java from Oracle official website...

Comment: Why would the 64-bit version of Java be the right one for the version of Eclipse you've downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Please update your JAVA jdk version